# Time Machine on Ubuntu Server via SSH tunnel - backup fails

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, backup, time-machine, tunnel

I have an `afpd` up on my Ubuntu server. Everythings works fine in LAN.
If I want to make a backup for a user via ssh tunnelling it fails, although it works in lan.
The tunnelling works fine. When the tunnel is established I can mount my existing backup without any problem.

`ssh L port -> localhost:548 (in the general sense)`

Also configuring the backup volume with Time Machine settings succeeds.
But when it wants to actually backup it pops up the error that there is an incorrect user or password.
My server shows me the following auth log:

> `afpd[2431]: pam_unix(netatalk:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=afpd ruser= rhost=localhost  user=xxx`

Does anybody has an hint how to rule out that problem?
Although I searched for this problem, it seems there is nobody with an analogous problem.

---

my sshd_config on the client is as following:

```
`Host *
SendEnv LANG LC_*`
```

my ssh_config on server side is:

> Port xx
>   Protocol 2
>   HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
>   HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
>   HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
>   HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
>   UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
>   KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
>   ServerKeyBits 1024
>   SyslogFacility AUTH
>   LogLevel VERBOSE
>   LoginGraceTime 120
>   PermitRootLogin no
>   StrictModes yes
>   RSAAuthentication yes
>   PubkeyAuthentication yes
>   IgnoreRhosts yes
>   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
>   HostbasedAuthentication no
>   PermitEmptyPasswords no
>   ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
>   X11Forwarding yes
>   X11DisplayOffset 10
>   PrintMotd no
>   PrintLastLog yes
>   TCPKeepAlive yes
>   AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
>   Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
>   UsePAM yes
>
> ---

Thanks in advance

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Is Time Machine set to allows `ssh` on that port?
Check `ssh_config`.
(You can find it with `locate ssh_config` and usually in located in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`).

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. Could you explain it? My understanding was that when i forward the port 548 via ssh, then for the client as well for the server it seems as they were in lan, or rather they use port 548 and it is as in lan.

Comment: that is correct but it appears the firewall on one side is NOT allowing that forwarding to happen..

Comment: thx again. on my server the ufw log is clean, there is no blocking of any used port. added my ssh_config above. so i m guessing i have to edit my ssh_config to define something corresponding to that forward?

Comment: are you referring to AllowTcpForwarding ? with that ssh_config it should be turned on, right?

Comment: guys i m roaming in the dark, any other hints?